# Can we access an ASP.NET web user control's child controls using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webusercontrol

I have a web user control. I want to know how to access its child control, using JavaScript, when we use it in another page.

Suppose my control is as below:

```
  <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UCS.ascx.cs" Inherits="UCS" %>
        <asp:Panel ID="rbtnPanel" runat="server">
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnEn" runat="server" GroupName="scan" Checked="true" Text="Entire" style="margin-left: -7px;"/>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnCu" runat="server" GroupName="scan" Text="Custom" style="position: absolute; margin-left: 2px;"/>
         </asp:Panel>
```

update:

I have added it in the page as: Try.aspx

```
 <%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/UCS.ascx" TagName="UCS" TagPrefix="ucSc" %>
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td>
          <usSc:UCS id="UCS1" runat="server" />
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

try.aspx: JavaScript:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setPageLayout(2, 0, true);
    startTimer();
  }

  function startTimer()
  {
    alert(document.getElementById("<%= rbtnCu.ClientID %>").checked);
  }
```

So if I use this control in another page by registering it. How can I access the RadioButton in that Try.aspx page's JavaScript section.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/?s=id%20selector), since the ClientIDMode for radio button is not static you will have to use ClientID as the id generated by asp.net is not what you see as a server id.

```
var rbrbtnEn =  document.getElementById('<%= rbtnEn.ClientID %>');
```

To get the checked status

```
alert(document.getElementById('<%= rbtnEn.ClientID %>').checked);
```

Comment: Thanks, But Its not working in the case of web user control, as its nested as custom control in the page. its throwing script error.

Comment: Make sure you access the element in document.ready or put script tag just before closing body tag. I have also updated my answer to do it using javascript not jQuery.

Comment: I tried it, but still I can't access radiobutton directly, I have edited my question for more clarification.

Comment: Please show me generated html and your javascript code in context to your page. Do you use jQuery?

Comment: I'm using javascript. Updated it in question. If I do this, its get redirected to my custom error page.

Comment: You are using $(document).ready( ... and that is jQuery and you need include jQuery library, otherwise you have to ensure the html controls (elements) you access in script should have rendered. See this article for using jQuery, http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: Then i should work, can you debug the code to see whats the problem?